# How to animate checkbox on touching other adjacent/parent views in Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-animation

I've got this layout: [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ4WE.png)

When I click on checkbox, it checks/unchecks with its default animation. I need to check/uncheck it  with animation even if I click on the textview.
Constraint: I can't use label for the checkbox, which would have solved this problem easily.

Need help :( Thanks.

I've tried calling **checkbox.toggle()**, **checkbox.performClick()** & **checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked** within onClick for the textview but none of them performs the touch animation on the checkbox, they simply just check/uncheck it.